# ASP.NET C# char Type displaying Special Character �

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an application that allows users to create applications. One of the fields in the application class is of data type char and named Offer. When I go to the create form to create an application. The Offer field is automatically filled with a special character � (is the square character). Why is this happening? I cannot convert the char to string either to allow a 1 character input.

I have tried:

```
char chr = 'X';
Offer = chr,

char chr = 'X';
string str = chr.ToString();
Offer = str,

char chr = 'X';
Offer = chr.ToString()

Offer = Char.ToString('X')

Offer = Convert.ToChar(88) #ASCII for X

Offer = ((char)0x0058).ToString(); #0x0058 Binary Unicode for X
```

Am I doing something horribly wrong?

HTML for input box:

```
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Offer, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Offer, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Offer, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Same encoding between both?

Comment: @Zer0 apologies, can you elaborate on what you mean by that?

Comment: I think this [introduction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding-introduction) is worth a read if you're new to the concept.

Comment: @Zer0 thank you! i'll have a read before bed

Comment: @Zer0 I've tried to code it into ASCII and Binary Unicode, still not working, I've edited to show what I have attempted.

Comment: And if you change that `Offer` in your display model to type `string` instead of `char`?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing It works as you'd imagine, however i'm just confused at how char works as a type and wanted to use it in 1 field. I thought it was just a type that holds 1 character that I can write as a string or int .